# QObject::connect: Cannot connect (particular signals) to (null)

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qdockwidget

I am trying to add multiple tab in QDockWidget which was inherited by class sView. For that I have written custom made signals and slots.
But I am getting following error.

```
QObject::connect: Cannot connect myView::EnableWindow() to (null)::ShowWindow()
```

mainWindow.h

```
class mainWindow : public mainWindow
Q_OBJECT       
public slots:
void ShowWindow();
```

mainWindow.cpp

```
void mainWindow::ShowWindow()
{
    if (!_sView->isHidden()) 
    {
        sView* newObject = new sView();
        addDockWidget(Qt::BottomDockWidgetArea,newObject );
        tabifyDockWidget(sView,newObject);
    }
}
```

sView.h

```
class sView : public QDockWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT      
signals:
    void EnableWindow();
}
```

sView.cpp

```
sView::sView() 
{     
    connect(this, SIGNAL(EnableWindow()), GetInstance()->GetMainWindowObj(),SLOT(ShowWindow()));
}
```

How to solve this problem ?

Comment: You are using Qt4 style signals. This has the disadvantage that wrong connections are discovered at run-time. Try [Qt5 style signals](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax). They will be checked by the compiler. Hence, you might find out much easier where things went wrong.

Comment: @Scheff'sCat : Thanks for warning about tag spamming.  Thank you once again.

Comment: @Scheff'sCat : I tried to connect with new way  like `connect(this, &guiSchematicView::EnableSchematicWindow,guiMgr::GetInstance()->GetMainWindowObj(),
            &guiMainWindow::ShowSchematicWindow);`    but I got follwing error :  `QObject::connect(guiSchematicView, Unknown): invalid null parameter`

Comment: @Scheff'sCat : Is he not getting  `guiMainWindow::ShowSchematicWindow`  ?

Comment: In this  case, use a debugger (or print debugging) and check the object pointers beforehand. One of them might not be what you think it is. In general, it might help if you would prepare and [edit] in a [mcve]. From your few code fragments, it's hard to say what the actual issue is.

Comment: It's hard to imagine that the member function pointers are the issue. A member function pointer cannot be absent. It's provided out of the code the compiler compiles, and it never changes at runtime. That's why a recommended to focus on the pointers of the objects (source as well as destination).

Comment: The error message is implying `guiMgr::GetInstance()->GetMainWindowObj()` evaluates to a null pointer.  That's the piece of code you need to debug first.

Comment: @G.M. Yes, you are right.  It is returnng `nullptr`. So I removed connect()  from constructor and define it in some function and called that function from different class.  And the error gone.  But what is the problem if I call it from constructor ?

Comment: Nobody can tell you what the problem is unless you show the relevant code.  As stated in other comments you need to run under a debugger to ascertain why a null pointer is being returned.